# Does Meego Nokia N950 support C++ QML binding?

Tags: c++, qt, nokia, qml, meego

I want to communicate between C++ and QML on Meego.  It happens using C++ QML binding as described in this [link](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qtbinding.html).

When I run an app on the Symbian platform it works, and data from C++ is available to manipulate in some QML file.

But on Meego it always says `myItem.qml file not found`.

See the following code snippet:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
     QApplication app(argc, argv);

     QDeclarativeView view;
     MyClass myClass;
     view.rootContext()->setContextProperty("myObject", &myClass);

     view.setSource(QUrl::fromLocalFile("MyItem.qml"));
     view.show();

     return app.exec();
 }
```

**Does Meego does not support QML C++ binding?**

I also tried to give the exact path of the QML file but never found that file, even myItem is in project structure.

**Is there some thing associated with path settings in .pro file etc**

Please help on this as I am stuck here with this and cannot move forward in my app using Qt Quick.

Comment: Have you tried these Meego sites? : http://appdeveloper.intel.com/en-us/article/meego-software-development-a-closer-look
 and 
http://appdeveloper.intel.com/en-us/blog/2011/05/19/packaging-qml-applications-meego

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but your problem isn't related to C++ and QML bindings.  Your application (specifically the view) can't find the .qml file to load.

By default, I think on meego the default path to look in is `../qml`.  So by default you should be packaging into `/opt/YOURNAME` with the binary in `/opt/YOURNAME/bin` and the qml files in `/opt/YOURNAME/qml`.

However, you can also put the qml files into a resource and use the `:/` paths to access a resource instead.

IE, in your resource file:

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/">
        <file>qml/foo.qml</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

And in C++:

```
viewer.setSource(QUrl("qrc:/qml/foo.qml"));
```